# Click event should fire on "readonly" datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, click, bootstrap-datepicker

What I want is to fire click event on readonly datepicker field. When I use readonly in that field It fires an event and also open calendar popup but I want to block that popup and only fire click event.

for example,
this is my text field for datepicker:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_datepicker" readonly>
```

and when I fire click event with that id as below:

```
$('#id_datepicker').click(function(){alert("Something here")})
```

So in this case only alert should open. not the calendar that pops up. So how it can be done?

just like this https://jsfiddle.net/qL3nwz4c/2/

Comment: To do this you would need to destroy the instance of the datepicker on that element: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy

Comment: It works when I write that snippet outside click function. but in my case I want to add that code snippet inside click event. so in that case it does not work .    https://jsfiddle.net/qh96wfmx/3/

Comment: salam did you try click(function(e){alert("Something here");
e.stopImmediatePropagation();})

Comment: @ZERROUKIAli sorry it's not working

Answer (score 1):

simply remove `#js-date` from your input so it cant be apply in your readonly input.

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aw15csyz/

Comment: yes it's working. Thanks but where I actually want to implement, it does not make any effect there. will check again

Comment: what are you want to say ?

Comment: I checked the fiddle and it is working the way I want. but the project in which I am working, this solution is not working ( I have implemented in the same way as I mentioned in question.)

Comment: so you want to add `js-date` id and disable datepicker, which input have `readonly` ?

Comment: No I am working with class and using it disable datepicker

Comment: don't forgot to consider up-vote and check this answer as best answer for you by clicking on right arrow, thanks!